# Do Check Engine Light Codes get Stored in ECM if the check Engine Light turns off on it's own?

Tags: automatic-transmission, corolla, cel, solenoid

I have a 2010 corolla with 166k miles on it. I have never had any major issues with the car. This past Saturday I drove about 300 miles and just as I was about to get home I got 3 lights that turned on on my dash: Check Engine Light, vsc, and traction control off. All 3 lit up at the same time. I did not notice any difference in the driving of the car, it changed gears, accelerated, broke etc... all normal. Using an OBD II scan tool I go the code p2757. P2757 is: `Torque Converter Clutch Pressure Control Solenoid Ctrl Circuit Performance or Stuck Off`. I let my car sit over night and today I turn my car on and the 3 lights have turned off. I make an appt to take it to Toyota in a couple of days but now that the light is off, will the Toyota techs still be able to pull up the code that appeared when the lights were on?

I DID NOT reset the battery as some folks do, I merely turned my car on like usual and the lights were gone.

1. So will the techs be able to pull up the code to diagnose the real issue?
2. Is it possible there is no issue with the car since the lights turned off on their own?
3. My car is due for emissions testing soon, will my car pass emissions now that the light is off or will it fail because the emissions testing station will find codes in the ECM's memory?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Yes they do....

Comment: So even though the lights turned off on their own, is there still an underlying issue that should be examined by a tech?

Comment: Yes, it is stored as a temporary code, it sets the check engine light when the problem is present, but if the issue goes away it turns the light off but stores the code, it is a pending issue that may return.

Comment: @Moab do you know why the lights would turn off on their own after the car sit in my garage for 1.5 days? Also will it pass emissions with a pending code?

Comment: @Moab - Please put your comments as an answer to the question. To the OP: Please don't ask more than one question at a time and especially don't use comments to ask them. Also, Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! :o)

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to my post, after going to Toyota they told me it is most likely the solenoid. They recommended replacing the entire tranny for $5600 as they said the cost of replacing the solenoid is VERY expensive, their reasoning was: There are a lot of internal transmission parts that need to be inspected and possibly replaced along with the solenoid if further internal issues were found and there is not guarantee that swapping the solenoid would actually fix the issue as code readers point to problem AREAS in the car, not specific parts. Thus the expensive cost. I passed as that is worth more than the price of my car!! The car drives perfectly fine, even when the lights are lit up. Some may bash because I am "ignoring" the underlying issue. I suppose I am, but what else can I do? Pay 3.5k-5.6k to replace the tranny? The car is worth 4k ok KBB if I am lucky. Just wanted to post an update, I will let you guys know if my car just dies out on me.